# how to remove class with a link that created with jquery html function

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I want that class remove from an element, when click on a link, that created with jquery html function

here is an example:

```
//script
  $("#test").click(function(){
       $("#body").html("<a href='#' id='removeclass'>removeclass</a>"); 
    });
   $("#removeclass").click(function(){
      $("#test").removeClass("anClass"); 
    });

//html

<div id="body"></div>
<button id="test" class="anClass">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#test").on('click',  function() {
       $("#body").html("<a href='#' id='removeclass'>removeclass</a>"); 
}); 
$("#removeclass").live('click',  function() {
        $("#test").removeClass("anClass"); 
});
```